# Date Picker appereace broke

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout

I'm using a fragment of code to open a DatePicker in Android programmatically:

Using the same API 28 targeting and Emulator, In my main project, the date picker show with this appearance:

[Main project](https://imgur.com/fwB6S9i)

While using the same code in another fresh project, it produce normal DatePicker:

[Fresh Project](https://imgur.com/a/8klLKKU)

The code is following:

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
int year = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
int month = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
int day = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(ScrollingActivity2.this, 
            new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {

                }
            }, year, month, day);
datePickerDialog.show();
```

I'm expecting to get the normal, default DatePicker, I'm feeling the problem is from theme or XML layout but cannot identified where is the error, any help is appreaciated.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem, it because i set the Color Accent Value as #FFFFFF in color.xml file (Which the accent looks great in other activity while unknowingly it will affect the Date Picker - the default Android apps and Date Picker use Red as accent)

Guess i have to manually set colors for each Activity for now.